# typescript correct type for svg component passed as prop

Tags: reactjs, typescript, svg, react-icons

I am building a button component:

```
interface ButtonProps {
   startIcon?: ... <-- what type?
}

const Button = ({startIcon: StartIcon}) => {
   return <button>{StartIcon && <StartIcon/>}</button>
}

// usage
<Button startIcon={SomeIcon}/>
```

I am using `react-icons` library, what type should I declare in interface? Does it make a difference on type declaration if I pass svg element as startIcon prop?

Comment: I believe react-icons offers an `IconType` type that might do the trick here

Answer (score 0):

The type of your icons is `FunctionComponent` so you can simply import it from `react` library:

```
import React, {FunctionComponent} from 'react';
// rest of the codes ...

interface ButtonProps {
  startIcon?: FunctionComponent 
}
```

##### Optional

You can check the type of your variables with a simple `console.log` and `typeof` method.

Assume this simple component:

```
const SampleComponent = () => <p>Hello</p>
```

Now check the type:

```
console.log(SampleComponent);
console.log(typeof SampleComponent) // function
```

Now, check the icons type (imported from react-icons), its is completely similar to above result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm late but it may be helpful for others

**You can define type of svg Icon in Functional Component like**

```
export interface IconProps {
  style?: StyleProp<ViewStyle>;
  fill?: string;
  width?: number;
  height?: number;
  text?: string;
  fill_1?: string;
  fill_2?: string;
  fill_3?: string;
  fill_4?: string;
}

interface ButtonProps {
startIcon?: ({ fill, width, height, style }: IconProps) => JSX.Element;
}

const Button = ({startIcon: StartIcon}:ButtonProps) => {
   return <button>{StartIcon && <StartIcon/>}</button>
}


//Usage
<Button startIcon={SomeIcon}/>
```